# Automatically detect image alpha, then crop and trim to separate files using imagemagick?

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, command-line, imagemagick

I often get images like the following from PSD file layers,

[image: Source image]

I'd like to make an imagemagick batch script where it finds the transparent and opaque areas of an image and separates the images one by one, so the above image would output as,

[image: Separate image files]

Could imagemagick do this? I tried to find something in the documentation, but all I got was cropping from set dimensions.

Comment: If the color circles are on separate and transparent layers simple `convert layered.psd ii_%2d.png` shout do the trick. However if the PSD is flattened then you should use extra script for the segmentation. But frankly I am not sure what the input is as you didn't attach the actual PSD.

Comment: Maybe [multicrop](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php)?

Comment: multicrop script looks good but it states that it is not free to port or use as you wish, I do need it on Windows.